# Writing XPATH for selecting certain nodes

Tags: xml

I have the following format of the XML document. Can you please let me know the XPATH for getting all parent nodes (For example reject and Addl in this case) for the given value of fromRole. Thanks for the help.

```
  <Movement>
     <Reject>
       <Status>
       </Status>
       <fromRole>
       </fromRole>
       <fRole>
       </fRole>    

     </Reject>
     <Addl>
       <Status>
       </Status>
       <fromRole>
       </fromRole>
       <fRole>
       </fRole>    
     </Addl> ....and so on
     .......................
  </Movement>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all immediate children of `Movement` assuming that `Movement` is a child of the root

```
/Movement/*
```

this will give you all children of `Movement` regardless of where `Movement` itself is in the tree hierarchy

```
'//Movement/*'
```

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Going up from `fromRole` accessing all immediate parents

```
'//fromRole/..'
```

it doesn't really matter what you have inside some nodes, what matters it what your current processing node is. The `//` is agnostic to the current location and will give you all matching nodes regardless of where they are in the tree.

Comment: HI - I think I didn't explain the question well. Redefining the XML to add more values. In the following XML, if I have the value of AA in <fromRole> values, then the XPATH should return the values Addl and Reject.

Comment: <Movement> 
         <Reject> 
           <Status></Status> 
           <fromRole>AA</fromRole> 
           <fRole></fRole>     
         </Reject> 
         <Addl> 
           <Status></Status> 
           <fromRole>AA</fromRole> 
           <fRole></fRole>     
         </Addl> ....and so on 
     ....................... 
      </Movement>